# How to write a get with no public set.

Tags: c#, get, set, public

Does anyone know how to do this? I need to write a String property named Title with a get (but no public set). A book's title is not allowed to change after it is created. No validation need be done on the title. You may use an auto-implemented property.

Comment: `string title = ""; public string Title { get { return title; } }` or `public string Title { get; private set }`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the access modifiers as you would with any field/method in your class. Which means you can use `private`, `protected` and `internal`. Properties are public by default.

Therefore you can do:

```
public string Title { get; private set; }
```

Or if you want to be able to set it from a derived class:

```
public string Title { get; protected set; }
```

You can read more about [Restricting Accessor Accessibility on MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx)